# How to control the bandwidth that can be used by other people connecting to wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, bandwidth

i searched for softwares that i could use and found the p2pover, but i think it only detects lan computers not the wireless. My relatives who uses the wifi causes the speed to become slow and i think that was unfair for us who is paying for the internet.

So is there any way i could control their bandwidth? router configuration? software that is free? or anything?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you don't want unpaying wifi users, change your WPA2 key (or employ such security if you haven't already).

In terms of simply limiting bandwidth, it depends on your router, but many firmwares have built in support for QoS management - Quality of Service. In this, you specify around 85-90% of your maximum connection speed (the one in from outside) and set some rules by which other devices are assigned their portion of your total bandwidth. Using the slightly lessened total bandwidth allows the router to queue traffic more efficiently and provide better service to the devices.

Check your router's web interface. If it comes with QoS, it'll be in there somewhere. If not, it is possible to perform with another device, but this means that device must route the traffic around (essentially replacing your router) to achieve the result.